# Onenote—I reinstalled Windows and now I can't open my .one files

Tags: microsoft-onenote

My computer crashed, so I copied my Documents folder off the drive before wiping everything with a fresh install of Windows. Now, I try to open the .one files (Microsoft OneNote) and the application says it can't open the file and I should try reopening the default notebook...

The rest of the internet says to export my notes differently, to make it easier for importing, but I've already wiped my computer, all I have is the .one files

Comment: What is the **exact** error message?

Comment: Sorry it's on a friend's computer, so I can't get the exact wording, but it said something like "Can't do this here. Try reopening the default notebook." But the current notebook opened is the only notebook existing at the moment.